# Issue with udf in scala, I'm not able to get expected result

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have Scala code where I'm using udf, through udf I'm doing some calculation and getting the status of that and try to log accordingly.I got stuck in the else part where I'm not able to print the log message in console.

```
val testRule1 = { (code: Int, type: String, pCode: String) =>

  if (code == 100 && type == "AK")

    if (pCode != " " && pCode != Nil.toString())
      true
    else 
    {
        validationMap("validation") = false
        logger.info("Doing nor stuff")
        false
    }

  else
        valMap("val") = false
        logger.info("Doing not stuff")
        false
}


val valRule1Udf = udf(testRule1)

val valmasterDF = valChildDF.withColumn("valRow", valRule1Udf(valChildDF("TYPE"), valChildDF("P_CODE"))).drop("validatingRowVD")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not even compile

1. there are several braces missing
2. You cannot have a variable called `type`, thats a reserved keyword
3. 'AK' ist nit a `Char`, this should be a `String`

   ```
   val testRule1 = { (code: Int, typ: String, pCode: String) =>
     if (code == 100 && typ == "AK") {
       if (pCode != " " && pCode != Nil.toString()) {
         true
       } else {
         validationMap("validation") = false
         logger.info("Doing nor stuff")
         false
       }
     } else {
       valMap("val") = false
       logger.info("Doing not stuff")
       false
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for your reply, after following your input in my code, I'm  getting this error  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type AnyVal is not supported`